# Ошибка при публикации приложения в google play

Tags: android

При публикации происходит ошибка, которую не понимаю как поправить

> Ошибка Для этого типа версии не выбраны страны и регионы. Добавьте
> хотя бы одну страну или регион

Что мне делать, чтобы она ушла, как выбрать страну или регион

Comment: Рабочая версия (или тестирование) закладка Страны и регионы, ниже добавить страны регионы?

Comment: Проверю, спасибо

Comment: Оно, @Style-7 спасибо

Comment: нет такого раздела (искал через поиск)